# Does SWT Table emit column created / removed events?

Tags: java, swt

Skimmed through the Eclipse API doc and found no mentioning of this event. Could I have missed something? I'm building something that lists all table columns in a given table, and it needs to be automatically updated if the set of columns in the Table changes, so I need to listen to the Table structure changes and update my list accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for doesn't exist.  You could add dispose listeners to the TableColumns, and that could tell you when one is removed, but there are no events for telling you when widgets are created.  You might be able to "fake it" by tracking control events on the table columns with TableColumn#addControlListener, but this is iffy.  If you have control of the tables you could do something more advanced by wrapping them in a dynamic proxy that could perform that function for you.